# How can I use Minim in Processing for computing FFT of UDP-streamed samples?

Tags: stream, udp, fft, processing, minim

I need to compute the FFT in real time on a stream. I receive packages with arrays of bytes through an UDP port. Is it possible to somehow convert them to a stream that Minim could analyze? I searched for a long time and found a few possible solutions (FloatSampleBuffer, createSample) but I was still lost as to how to compute the FFT out of that.